# How to to save txt file on server in HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making signup form stuff and  I want to save data to server and I got this code :

```
function Signup()
   {
     var text = "hello world",
   blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' }),
   anchor = document.createElement('a');

anchor.download = "hello.txt";
anchor
anchor.href = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
anchor.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', anchor.download, anchor.href].join(':');
anchor.click();
   }
```

But its download file and I'm wondering how to save/download it to server.

Comment: which server you are using ? express ?

Comment: You need to implement a Backend (software running *on the webserver*) to achieve this. And then the Frontend can instruct or request the Backend to do this for you. To do this safely and securely, you might also want to implement a kind of authentication.

Comment: using normal https server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The code you have found is for triggering a download and saving a file to the browser's download directory (client-side).

It would be a serious security risk for a web browser to be able to write to arbitrary files on the server.

Instead, create a web service (using the server side programming language of your choice) and make an HTTP request to it (e.g. by submitting a form or using `fetch`).

Note that for a sign up system, you are almost certainly going to want to save the data to a database and not to a file (that is still a matter for server-side code though).

Comment: I got my own server I just want to make login form but  how

Comment: @apple — Step 1: Pick a programming language. Step 2: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tutorial+login+system+insert+programming+language+here

Comment: HTML count or not?

Comment: HTML is not a programming language.

Comment: HTML - Hypertext Markup Language If still not then what do u recommend?

Comment: Note "Markup Language" not "Programming Language". You could use JavaScript (via Node.js), Perl, Python, C# (via ASP.NET), Java, Ruby, PHP. Any programming language.

Comment: Interesting tysm!